# by viewModels None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I've tried every incantation I could find but still have a problem using by viewModel.

Here is the code in question:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(), OnSneakerClickListener, OnSneakerDismissListener {
private val httpclient = OkHttpClient()
val stripe = Stripe(this, "pk_test_yadayadayada")
private val viewModel: StripeIntentViewModel by viewModels() //<--dragons be here
```

When I manually type in "import androidx.activity.viewModels" it shows it as an "unused import directive".

My module build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'checkstyle'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize'
 }
 ...
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
...
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$androidLifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$androidLifecycleVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentVersion"
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-rc01"
```

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 12):

The [`by viewModels()` property extension](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/package-summary#viewmodels) is an extension on [`androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity), which is what provides support for ViewModels (via the `ViewModelStoreOwner` interface).

`FlutterActivity`, as per its [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/app/FlutterActivity.html), only extends `android.app.Activity` and does not extend `ComponentActivity`. Therefore it is not possible to use `by viewModels()` from a `FlutterActivity`.

You can instead use [`FlutterFragmentActivity`](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/app/FlutterFragmentActivity.html), which extends `FragmentActivity` (which itself extends `ComponentActivity`) as per [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45678#issuecomment-575411589).

Comment: Thanks! I was suspecting it could be Flutter related. I resorted to "the old way" doing: private val model: StripeIntentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(instance).get(StripeIntentViewModel::class.java) but might convert over to this.